# Async function returns Promis {'...'}

Tags: javascript

I am try to learn WebdriverIO and was trying to use things I did 'learn', but I came across an issue with Promises.
I have 2 js files: Page and test.

Page I have following

```
get listOfElements() { return $$('[selector]')}


async getTextOfElements(element) {
    let item = await element;
    let textOfElement= [];
    return textOfElement= await item.map(async i => await i.getText());
}
```

test inside of describe/it blocks

```
const printOut await Page.getTextOfElements(await Page.listOfElements);
console.log(printOut);
```

console prints following:

```
[
    Promise{'sometext'},
    Promise{'sometext'},
    Promise{'sometext'},
    Promise{'sometext'},
]
```

It works if the element is referred to directly inside the function:

**Page.js **

```
get listOfElements() { return $$('[selector]')};


async getTextOfElements() {
    let textOfElement= [];
    return textOfElement= await this.listOfElements.map(async i => await i.getText());
}
```

**test.js** inside of describe/it blocks

```
const printOut await Page.getTextOfElements();
console.log(printOut);
```

I tried new Promise with resolve and reject but did get same result. From what I read, using async/await should have resolved that issue, but I am obviously missing something. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: `item.map(async`  you can't use `async` with map like that unfortunately,  but a simple fix is to use `for (let i of item)` instead and push into the array.

Comment: Thank you for response, Keith. `for of` does work, but I was hoping that I was doing something wrong and there is a way for `item.map(asyn)` to work (

Comment: That's completely false. It's just a callback function, of course you can make it async.

Comment: @DallogFheir  What's completely false?.    Using `map` with `await` will do nothing, because `map` doesn't return a `Promise`, it returns an array.  You could of course place this into `Promise.all()` and `await` that.

Comment: What you said is completely false: *item.map(async you can't use async with map like that unfortunately*. You can use async with map like that, it's awaiting the result of map that does nothing, which you didn't mention at all in your previous comment. Instead you suggested using a for loop for some reason.

Comment: @DallogFheir  What are you on about?, I clearly showed the OP what to do to allow him to achieve his goals.   I suggested using a Loop because that works.  The OP even acknowledged it worked.  It's maybe time you learnt a bit more about `async / await` & Promises before you claim others are completing wrong.

Comment: Oh please point me to a resource where I can learn why "you can't use async with map like that unfortunately", I'm very curious because it clearly works and that statement is completely wrong.

Comment: @DallogFheir  Tell you what, why not try and use `map(async` and try and `await` it, and see what happens.  I clearly stated in my comment -> `with map like that unfortunately`, I never said you can't use `async` inside a callback.  Note again,  `Like That`, read the context of the answer.